# Terraform dynamic block with for_each

Tags: azure, terraform

Need suggestion.
I am trying to run the below code. First adf is imported which has the vsts configuration.
For second adf, i dont need the vsts configuration. I have tried using dymanic block, but getting error as below.

on main.tf line 16, in resource "azurerm_data_factory" "adf":
2020-12-24T08:13:44.3101544Z   16:   dynamic [4m"action"

[0m {
2020-12-24T08:13:44.3101802Z [0m
2020-12-24T08:13:44.3102076Z Blocks of type "action" are not expected here.

Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "adf"{

for_each = var.purposes
name=lower("${var.component}-${var.project}-${var.regionname}-${var.azureregion}-${var.environment}-${each.value.purpose}")

  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
 

  identity{
    
    type="SystemAssigned"
    
    
  }

  dynamic "action" {
  for_each = var.vsts_config ? [1] : []
  
content {

  vsts_configuration {
    
    account_name = var.accountname
    branch_name = var.branchname
    project_name = var.projectname
    repository_name = var.repository
    tenant_id       = "__tenantId__"
    root_folder     = var.rootfolder

    }
  
}


  }

}

input.tfvars
purposes = {
  a =  {
        purpose = "load",
        
    }
  b =  {
        purpose = "live",
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`action` is not a valid block in [azurerm_data_factory](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory). If you want to make `vsts_configuration` block optional, then you code should be:

```
dynamic "vsts_configuration" {

    for_each = var.vsts_config ? [1] : []
  
    content {
        account_name    = var.accountname
        branch_name     = var.branchname
        project_name    = var.projectname
        repository_name = var.repository
        tenant_id       = "__tenantId__"
        root_folder     = var.rootfolder  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code , but while running terraform apply the vsts configuration is stiil getting added  for the second adf.

Comment: @Sourav It will be added when `var.vsts_config` is true.

Comment: var.vsts_config is by default set as false. In the code for_each = var.vsts_config ? [1] : []                                                                                              when terraform plan  runs, first adf which was imported vsts_configuration value changes to null.